# Привязка текста элемента к ToggleButton у Expander

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Не могу придумать как это сделать. Нужно чтобы при нажатии на экспандер сообщение текстблока менялось на "Скрыть описание", а при повторном нажатии (когда он снова сворачивается), чтобы надпись опять становилась "Показать описание".

```
<Expander>
  <Expander.Header>
    <TextBlock Text="Показать описание"/>
  </Expander.Header>
<Expander>
```

Была идея привязать текст текстблока к ToggleButton этого экспандера, а потом через конвертер это реализовать, но только я не знаю как эту привязку сделать, ведь мы имеем только сам экспандер, а не ToggleButton внутри него. Надеюсь на вашу помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто сделайте нужный стиль и добавьте в него триггер.

1. Уберем из вашего кода все и зададим внутри переопределение стиля:

   ```
   <Expander>
       <Expander.Style>
           <Style TargetType="Expander">

           </Style>
       </Expander.Style>
   </Expander>
   ```
2. Далее задаем в стиле стандартные значения:

   ```
   <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" />
   <Setter Property="Header" Value="Показать описание" />
   ```
3. Теперь создаем триггер, который будет менять свойство `Header`, если `IsExpanded == true`:

   ```
   <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Header" Value="Скрыть описание" />
       </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
   ```

Итоговый результат:

```
<Expander>
    <Expander.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Expander">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="Показать описание" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="Скрыть описание" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Expander.Style>
</Expander>
```

[image: Result]